# Migration techniques: copy the entire database to v2 or change always on the same database version?

Tags: database, migration

I know the title might be confusing, but it's the best I could came with in order to explain the question.

**Background:**

I have a domain, a domain has 2 databases: one nosql (Mongodb) and one sql (Postgres); each database have their models. For example if the domain name is "myapp" and the version is "v01" then it will have a database named "myapp_v01" in both the sql and nosql.

**Migration - copy database:**

When I migrate I usually create a new database named like this "myapp_v02" (notice the 2). Then the migration script will clone tables or will get data from "myapp_v01" alter it somehow and save it to "myapp_v02" in a different way. I don't know if this will be very scalable or how it will be when it will take 1 hour to make the migration?

**Migration - copy tables:**

I could simply create a new temporary table to make the migration changes (copy from table "cars" to "cars_temp", then drop the "cars" table and change the name of "cars_temp" to "cars").

**Migration - alter tables:**

This is a little bit more tricky because we have both sql database.
In sql I would need to make the alter schema first and then somehow update each row when needed.

**Conclusions:**
I think the 3th one is the fastest one but I don't really know what are the best practices here.

Thanks

Comment: i think the third option is a good one - of course "it depends".

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider the third the default approach. It has a couple of arguments in favor:

1. You don't have to touch things you do not change. It just stays where it is like it is.
2. You can easily do phased changes, like  adding a column in v1, starting to fill it with data during the lifetime of version one, possibly in batches, actively using it in v2 and possibly deleting an old column in v3 when you are really sure all the new stuff is working nicely. Sounds cumbersome to do that in the other aproaches.
3. With large databases copying all the data might be prohibitivly expensive (more thinking about time and I/O than disk space)

UPDATE Answering the additional question in the comment

If you want to merge to columns A and B into a new column C you have various options based on the third approach from your question:

The Safe Way: 
- stop the application, so nobody can write to it.

- create and fill the column C
- possibly remove not null and similar constraints on A and B
- deploy and start new version of application which only uses column C.
- any time later drop column A and B, possibly only weeks later with the next release.

The quick Way
- stop the application, so nobody can write to it.

- create and fill the column C
- drop A and B
- deploy and start new version of application which only uses column C.

Since you seem to have problems with your application and unused columns, this might be the way to go.

The Way For Legacy Code
- create the column C (note: all apps are still running)

- create triggers that keep A,B and C in sync (this can also be done with views and possibly other vendor specific RDBMS features)
- deploy and start new version of application which only uses column C.
- migrate all other application to only use C
- any time later drop column A and B, possibly years later.

This is for cases where you have lots of apps using the db that you can't change all at once.

I have no idea about sequelize in mongoose ... sounds like a fairy tale adventure to me :-)

Comment: I still have a question about it. Imagine I have table_v01 with fields "a1" and "b2" and I want to merge them into "a2". I should create first the "a2" field but then I will have problems because I use models and the model in v2 doesn't have the fields "a1" and "b1" and the model in v1 doesn't have the "b2". Im using sequelize in mongoose.

Comment: My intent is to create a migration folder where contains the models at v1, v2, v3 for example. The models in the main app are the actual version models. So in my 1st way of doing I open 2 connections, one with the models at the v1 and another to the v2 and then copy-paste. But in the 3th way I don't know how to do it with the models...